# How to set values in mat-select from the class?

Tags: angular, combobox, angular-material

I am trying to explorig angular. This is my angular code.

**HTML Component**

```
     <mat-form-field class="select-country-component">
          <mat-label>Select Country</mat-label>
         <mat-select id="countries" class="tar-selector" (selectionChange)="getCountryDetails($event.value)">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.id">
            {{country.name}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Why loading if there is any value saved in localstorage then I wanted to set the select box value from my class.

**TS code**

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("COUNTRYSELECTED") !=""){
    // set value of localStorage.getItem("COUNTRYSELECTED") here
    }
```

How to achieve this in a simple way ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) directive from [FormsModule](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormsModule) for 2-way data binding:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <mat-form-field class="select-country-component">
      <mat-label>Select Country</mat-label>
      <mat-select id="countries" class="country-selector" [(ngModel)]="value" (ngModelChange)="getCountryDetails($event)">
         <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.id">
           {{country.name}}
         </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  `
}) class MyComponent {
  value: string;
  countries = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("COUNTRYSELECTED")){
       this.value = localStorage.getItem("COUNTRYSELECTED");
    }
  }

  getCountryDetails(countryId: string) {
     // some code
  }
```

}

Comment: in this [(ngModel)]="value" , what is "value" , Is it a variable kind?

Comment: it's just variable from the component class (updated sample)

Comment: Values are not setting in the combo box. I gave a different name for the value remaining all are same as the code given by you. I can see the values printed in the console but not getting populated on screen.